# How to Monitor Active Directory Queries

Tags: active-directory, ldap, monitoring

We are working to publish more data to our Active Directory address book.

We would like to know if there are any strategies to monitor when users or applications perform an LDAP query against Active Directory to read data.

How would we configure our domain controllers to log these sorts of events?
Is monitoring these types of LDAP queries even achievable through Windows Event Logs?

An example of a query we would like monitored or logged is when an account pulls a list of all User objects in Active Directory.

Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to [capture the LDAP requests](https://communities.ca.com/docs/DOC-231150484) and report from there, if your requests are encrypted you will have to configure Wireshark accordingly

An alternative would be to use Active Directory Collector sets in Performance Monitor as explained in [this article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2012/11/11/mcm-active-directory-indexing-for-the-masses/) which seems to show LDAP queries, but the article gets technical fast!

Comment: I prefer not to use Wireshark - I would like to use something that Microsoft provides out of the box. What about Active Directory Diagnostic Logging? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961809.aspx Is that a potential option?

Comment: You can monitor windows security logs on domain controllers to see which objects are accessed or modified

Comment: Do you know if those logs are available by default or do we have to modify the log settings using GPO to turn on more verbose logging?

Comment: You have to configure gpo and audit security settings for accounts you want to log events for or everyone to log events on action, performed by any account or you can configure advanced audit settings (https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2017/03/29/step-by-step-enabling-advanced-security-audit-policy-via-ds-access/)